# msal-browser failed in Office Addin Dialog API

Tags: reactjs, azure, office-addins, msal.js, msal-react

I am trying to use `@azure/msal-browser` and `@azure/msal-react` to enable Excel addin support microsoft sso and access Graph api.

Due to that Excel addin does not support access external url from Excel taskpane, i need to access `@azure/msal-browser` in dialog api which can be referece [Enable single sign-on (SSO) in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins).

If I use `PublicClientApplication` in normail excel addin project like react [React single-page application using MSAL React to authenticate users against Azure AD for Customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial-1-sign-in-react/), I am able to access the authorize consent page.

But, I open the page from dialog api like below:

```
 Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://localhost:3000/dialog.html', {height: 30, width: 20, displayInIframe: true});
```

And in the dialog page, it will call

```
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
```

I will throw error below:

[image]

This specific to `@azure/msal-browser` version `^3.7.0`, if I switch to `^2.28.1`, the error will gone.